# iframe + picture button + a href

Tags: html, image, button, iframe

First, I am still noob yet and I need some help from everyone... for my blogspot....
I try to make my own button click, with png and the button will direct to another url link once it clicked. And also I wish it able in iframe so people who use android/ios/pc can see it my blogspot.

(Just blogspot, no css and no php, beside I am still use blospot about 2 months....)

```html
<html>
<head>
<br>
<div style="position:relative;">
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no"  src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-pPllYfg1wF8/VUDnsXa3feI/AAAAAAAAABM/KLVqubELa9Q/s1600/button%26player2.PNG" /></iframe>
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="position:absolute; top:0 ; left:0; right:0; down:0; display:outline-block;  width:279px; height:31px;"></a>
</div>
<div style="position:relative;">
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no"  src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-pPllYfg1wF8/VUDnsXa3feI/AAAAAAAAABM/KLVqubELa9Q/s1600/button%26player2.PNG" /></iframe>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; down:0; display:outline-block; width:279px; height:31px;"></a>
</div>
</html>
```

The wide between 2 button are very far, and I wish someone can able help me fix it the button like this image:
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-7XZRNzt3gSY/VUOXiKCy2qI/AAAAAAAAABg/TjJBXBMsYdw/s1600/zz.PNG

Thank you!!

Comment: Why are you using iframes?

Comment: Good question!! Now most everyone have andriod/iphone surfing internet. If everything in my blogspot are using html5 + iframe, everything will display properly and very well in their andriod/iphone. I have tested my blog with all my old android (included Samsung Galaxy Y with Android 2.3) and iPhone 4s. And the best of all answer is iframe!!

Comment: You are the one adding the iframes code to your Blogspot, why not add inline styles to them too? And I don't fully understand the logic behind the use of iframes, it's just an image with a link, even older versions of Android/iPhone should be able to support that without an iframe

Comment: No use..... my old Samsung Galaxy Y unable display the button...